# Como criar propriedade em um objeto em Python?

Tags: python, objetos

Como posso criar um objeto com propriedade e adicionar em uma list de objeto usando o python?

Eu tenho uma funtion que espera um retorno de uma lista de produtos, esse retorno é usado por outras futions e não quero altera o tipo de retorno, por isso estou tentando monta o mesmo objeto do tipo list.

A ideia se simplesmente add um objeto em uma lista, mas estou tendo alguns erro a cada vez que tento algo diferente.

Como no caso abaixo tenho o erro:

> 0:"'object' object has no attribute 'UrlTermo'"

Bem na linha `produto.UrlTermo = termo.TermoDescricao`

```
buscaproduto: list = []

produto: object = object()
produto.UrlTermo: str
produto.UrlTermo = termo.TermoDescricao
buscaproduto.append(produto)
```

Comment: Pergunta: por que não criar a classe `Produto` para utilizá-la ali?

Comment: @Woss, as funtion que chama esse código não espera um tipo tipado, também não sei se posso fazer o append de um tipo para lista e não causa problema depois

Comment: No Python não existe "tipo tipado". Pode fazer tranquilamente.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algumas pesquisas e do comentário do @Woss, consegui resolver com uma classe.

```
class Produto(object):
    def __init__(self, termo: str, qtdRegistros: int, descricao:str, tipoConsulta:str):
        self.UrlTermo = termo
        self.QtdRegistros = qtdRegistros
        self.Descricao = descricao
        self.TipoConsulta = tipoConsulta
```

Chamando da seguinte forma:

```
produto = Produto(termo.TermoDescricao, 1, termo.TermoBusca, 'Termo')
buscaproduto.append(produto)
```

Comment: Se quiser, pesquise também por dataclasses